# How to findout whether render is finished in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a react native component which is connected to the store, whenever there is an update to the store, render method is invoked.
I want to know whether render finished rendering the page.
I tried `componentDidUpdate()` but is getting invoked for every update from the redux store.

Comment: `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount will be called after the first initial render.
componentDidUpdate will be called after all other renders.

See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) under lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for your response. componentDidUpdate will get called for every state update. So how do we know when the final update happened? We need this information to log an event for analytics which should happen only once after page is rendered.

Comment: But won't re-render only happen after a state change? After it's new render is done, componentDidUpdate will be called? I thought so, sorry.